# Замена изображения рабочего стола C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Пишу программу - шутник, меняющую фоновое изображение рабочего стола. Проблема в том, что функция ставит вместо заложенного изображения

```
LPWSTR str = (LPWSTR)"C:\\Users\Admin\Desktop\sr2.bmp";

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, str, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

черный фон. С чем это может быть связано и как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Возможно нужно экранировать символ '\' -- вместо одного слэша поставить два.

Comment: [ссылка]http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/simvolnye-konstanty-s-obratnym-sleshem

Comment: а ещё добавить `L` к строковому литералу, чтобы получилась широкая строка...

Comment: Ответ уже есть, но на будущее - не надо так делать: `(LPWSTR)"..."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться не-wide вариантом функции - SystemParametersInfoA (по умолчанию при компиляции используется wide SystemParametersInfoW)

```
char* str = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sr2.bmp";
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, str, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```